# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm having this problem: **No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has been registered.** In asp.net core 1.0, it seems that when the action try to render the view i have that exception.

I've searched a lot but I dont found a solution to this, if somebody can help me to figure out what's happening and how can I fix it, i will appreciate it.

My code bellow:

My **project.json** file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"

    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

My **Startup.cs** file

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using OdeToFood.Services;

namespace OdeToFood
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration configuration { get; set; }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddScoped<IRestaurantData, InMemoryRestaurantData>();
            services.AddMvcCore();
            services.AddSingleton(provider => configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            //app.UseRuntimeInfoPage();

            app.UseFileServer();

            app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }

        private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
        {
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it happening to a specific page ? What are you trying to do in that page ? Also when you comment out the  registration of `IRestaurantData`, were you able to replicate the issue ?

Comment: @Shyju, thanks for the replay, it's happening just when I try to call the View() method for display a view in any action of my homeController, always even I dont overload the method It always throw the exception, also when I comment the `IRestaurantData` registration service the issue still happening, is so weird this problem :( because it seems like I'm missing some namespace orsomething but the vs don't show me anything wrong in the code

Comment: @Shyju this are the namespace i'm using:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`
`using OdeToFood.ViewModels;`
`using OdeToFood.Services;`
`using OdeToFood.Entities;`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Solution:** Use `AddMvc()` instead of `AddMvcCore()` in `Startup.cs` and it will work.

Please see this issue for further information about why:

> For most users there will be no change, and you should continue to use
>   AddMvc() and UseMvc(...) in your startup code.
>
> For the truly brave, there's now a configuration experience where you
>   can start with a minimal MVC pipeline and add features to get a
>   customized framework.
>
> https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2872

You might also have to add a reference
to`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeature` in `project.json`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/

Answer (score 67):

If you're using `2.x` then use `services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine();` in your `ConfigureServices`

Also remember to add `.AddAuthorization()` if you're using `Authorize` attribute, otherwise it won't work.

Update: for `3.1` onwards use `services.AddControllersWithViews();`

Comment: Thank your for you answer. For our Project it was this one: 
services.AddControllersWithViews();

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 31):

I know this is an old post but it was my top Google result when running into this after migrating an MVC project to .NET Core 3.0. Making my `Startup.cs` look like this fixed it for me:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In .NET Core 3.1, I had to add the following:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

in `ConfigureServices()`

And the below in `Configure()` in `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapRazorPages();
}
```

Comment: keyword is NET Core 3.1, these two lines helped me right away

Answer (score 3):

In 2022 with .NET 6.0,

Add this line to Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); //After this line...
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(); //<--This line
```

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Core 2.0, in ConfigureServices, use :

```
services.AddNodeServices();
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Use `services.AddMvcCore(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddRazorViewEngine();`  in Startup.cs and it will work.

This code is tested for asp.net core 3.1 (MVC)

Answer (score 2):

For Net Core (NET 6.0 or above using VS 2022) this error may happen when trying to consume views. To avoid this issue don't forget when configuring Program.cs to use AddControllersWithViews instead of AddControllers

An Example of the fix:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApp.Net.Core.Api.EF.Core.Angular.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var configurationService =  builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext1>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configurationService.GetConnectionString("appSetttingsCon1")));
//builder.Services.AddControllers();//this will trigger the error when consuming views
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();//this fixes the issue
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now i has same problem, I was using AddMcvCore like you. I found error self descriptive, as an assumption I added AddControllersWithViews service to ConfigureServices function and it fixed problem for me. (I still use AddMvcCore as well.)

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvcCore();
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code and it should work:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
                    .AddViews();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that get this issue during .NetCore 1.X -> 2.0 upgrade, update both your `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}

public class Startup
{
// The appsettings.json settings that get passed in as Configuration depends on 
// project properties->Debug-->Enviroment Variables-->ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
    // no change to this method leave yours how it is
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for my case :

```
services.AddMvcCore()
.AddApiExplorer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this in startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<PartialViewResultExecutor>();
```

Comment: This just led me down a rabbit hole. I had to register all these other interfaces as well, and I couldn't find an implementation for the top one:
```cs
    .AddScoped<ITempDataProvider, >()
    .AddSingleton<ITempDataDictionaryFactory, TempDataDictionaryFactory>()
    .AddSingleton<ICompositeViewEngine, CompositeViewEngine>()
    .AddSingleton<PartialViewResultExecutor>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using VS 2022 and .NET 6.

The following line was giving me the error as described, and I incorrectly tried removing the entire line, but that did not work. The offending line:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

It was as simple as removing the SetCompatibilityVersion part:

```
services.AddMvc()
```